# Is there is way to set pagination arrows to be enabled even there is no data?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

how can i set pagination arrows to be enabled even there is no data or even if i'll use a condition to switch disable/enable[Pagination Arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw5vI.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Truncate from 'react-truncate';

// Material-UI
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import MaterialTable, { MTableToolbar, TablePagination } from 'material-table';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Zoom from '@material-ui/core/Zoom';

// Components
import Entity from '~/Components/Entity';
import violationsStyles from './styles';
import Strings from '~/Services/Strings';

// Services
import Navigate from '~/Services/Navigate';


@withStyles(violationsStyles)
class Violations extends React.Component {

state = {
  data : [],
  pageIndex: 0,
  pageSize: 1,
  totalCount: 0
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.get();
}

get() {
  const { pageIndex, pageSize } = this.state;

  this.entity.get({ pageIndex, pageSize });
}

get options() {
  return {
    actionsColumnIndex: -1,
    pageSize: 10,
    filtering: true,
    columnsButton: true,
    maxBodyHeight: 550,
    doubleHorizontalScroll: true,
    headerStyle: {
      color: '#434343',
      fontSize: 13
    }
  };
}

get localization() {
  return {
    header: {
      actions: '',
    },
    body: {
      emptyDataSourceMessage: Strings.listEmptyLabel,
    },
    pagination: {
      labelRowsPerPage: Strings.rowsPerPageLabel,
      labelDisplayedRows: `{from}-{to} ${Strings.fromText} {count}`,
    },
    toolbar: {
      addRemoveColumns: Strings.addRemoveColumns,
      showColumnsTitle: Strings.showColumnsTitle
    },
  };
}

get columns() {
  const { classes } = this.props;

  return [
    { title: Strings.violationReferenceNumber, field: 'referenceNumber', cellStyle: { width: 110 } },
    { 
      title: Strings.violationDescription, 
      field: 'description',
      render: rowData => (
        <Typography>
          <Truncate lines={1} ellipsis={<span>... </span>}>
            {rowData.description}
          </Truncate>
        </Typography>
      ),
      cellStyle: { paddingLeft: 0 }
    },
    { title: Strings.violationPenalty, 
      field: 'penaltyTypeId', 
      lookup: { 
        1: Strings.inform,
        2: Strings.alert,
        3: Strings.suspension, 
      },
      cellStyle: { width: '120px' }
    },
    {
      title: Strings.violationStatus,
      field: 'isArchived',
      lookup: {
        false: Strings.violationIsNotSettled,
        true: Strings.violationIsSettled,
      },
      cellStyle: { width: '130px' },
      defaultFilter: [ 'false' ]
    },
    {
      title: Strings.listActionsLabel,
      field: 'isArchived',
      render: rowData => (
        <div className={classes.iconWrapper}>
          <Choose>
            <When condition={rowData.isArchived === 'true'}>
              <Tooltip TransitionComponent={Zoom} title={Strings.violationEditActionOn}>
                <span>
                  <IconButton disabled={rowData.isArchived === 'true'}>
                    <EditIcon fontSize="default"/>
                  </IconButton> 
                </span> 
              </Tooltip>
            </When>
            <Otherwise>
              <IconButton disabled={rowData.isArchived === 'true' ? true : false} onClick={() => Navigate.go(`/violations/editor/${rowData.id}`)}>
                <Tooltip TransitionComponent={Zoom} title={Strings.violationListEditLabel}>
                  <EditIcon fontSize="default"/>   
                </Tooltip>
              </IconButton>
            </Otherwise>
          </Choose>
        </div>
      ),
      filtering: false,
      cellStyle: { paddingLeft: 35, paddingRight: 75, textAlign: 'left', justifyContent: 'flex-end', display: 'flex' },
      headerStyle: { paddingLeft: 35, textAlign: 'left', }
    },
  ];
}                          

get components() {
  const { classes } = this.props;

  return {
    Toolbar: props => (
      <div className={classes.toolbar}>
        <MTableToolbar {...props} />

        <div className={classes.customActionsBar}>
          <Button component={NavLink} to={'/violations/editor'} variant={'outlined'} color={'primary'}>
            <AddIcon className={classes.rightIcon} />
            {Strings.addNewViolation}
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.tabelSecondHeader}>
          <Typography variant='h6'>
            {Strings.listOfViolations}
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </div>
    ),
    Pagination: props => (
      <TablePagination {...props}
        count={this.state.totalCount}
      />
    ),
  };
}

onEntityReceived(data) {
  const arr = data.result;
  const mutableList = [];

  if(arr && arr.length > 0) {
    arr.map(item => {
      mutableList.push({ 
        ...item,
        isArchived: item.isArchived.toString()
      });
    });

    this.setState({ 
      data: mutableList,
      totalCount: data.totalCount
    });
  }
}

render() {
  const { data } = this.state;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Helmet>
        <title>
          {Strings.violationsManegment}
        </title>
      </Helmet>

      <Entity
        storeId={'Supervision-Violations'}
        entityRef={ref => { this.entity = ref; }}
        onEntityPosted={() => this.onEntityPosted()}
        onEntityReceived={data => this.onEntityReceived(data)}
        render={store => (
          <MaterialTable
            title={Strings.violationsManegment}
            data={data}
            isLoading={store.loading}
            options={this.options}
            localization={this.localization}
            columns={this.columns}
            components={this.components}
            onChangePage={pageIndex => this.setState({ pageIndex })}
            onChangeRowsPerPage={pageSize => this.setState({ pageSize })}
          />
        )}
      /> 
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
}

Violations.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object,
};

export default Violations;
```

i need to update the count of table because i'm getting the data from back-end and i'm using server side pagination technique and it appears that the total counts automatically be the total rows received unless i mutated it to be be total count that i received from endpoint because i receive some data per page

Answer (score 2):

Use `nextIconButtonProps={{disabled:false}}` and `backIconButtonProps={{disabled:false}}`

Answer (score 0):

could you try using the override that is explained here https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding. 
Use the code above to try to find a way of that you want. Right now there isnt a property that you can do that in a easy way.

```
components={{

                  Pagination: props => (
                    <TablePagination
                      {...props}
                      rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20, 30]}
                      rowsPerPage={this.state.numberRowPerPage}
                      count={this.state.totalRow}
                      page={
                        firstLoad
                          ? this.state.pageNumber
                          : this.state.pageNumber - 1
                      }
                      onChangePage={(e, page) =>
                        this.handleChangePage(page + 1)
                      }
                      onChangeRowsPerPage={event => {
                        props.onChangeRowsPerPage(event);
                        this.handleChangeRowPerPage(event.target.value);
                      }}
                    />
                  ),

                }}
```

Comment: what do u mean by this part ? 
page={
                        firstLoad
                          ? this.state.pageNumber
                          : this.state.pageNumber - 1
                      }

Comment: i got an error 
```invariant.js:42 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.```
here is my import statement
    `import MaterialTable, { MTableToolbar, TablePagination } from 'material-table';`

Comment: and this my Components Getter

Comment: That is import issues, maybe you are importing wrong something or the name doesnt exist in the component, check if you wrote correctly, im not sure.

Comment: Hi, @SalamaMohammed , I really dont understand, what is your actual error, you at the beginning ask for change the total count and this is the line count={this.state.totalRow}  , if that help you, please check my answer like the answer,

The import error is not related with Material Table, so could you create another stack overflow question or at least create a codesandbox with your code in order to understand better what is missing in your code. It is very difficult to read here because i can find what "import" is missing in your code, i hope you understand me. Best Regards